# Grails resources wrapper for IE

Tags: grails

How can I add multiple files to resource url without adding them one after another.

```
resource url:[dir:'css',file:'ie8.css'], attrs:[media:'screen'], wrapper: { s -> "<!--[if IE 8]>$s<![endif]-->" }
```

I tried doing this but it didn't work.

```
resource url:[dir:'css',file:'ie8.css ie8File2.css'], attrs:[media:'screen'], wrapper: { s -> "<!--[if IE 8]>$s<![endif]-->" }
```

I'm hoping I just don't have to keep stacking them.